# Managing detection of duplicate file names

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to detect a users Steam games that are installed on their computer, I wish to be able to find the appropriate .exe for each installation and backtrack through the directory to get the full path.

I've realized that there are several different games that use the same name for the executable file (hl2.exe) but they are in different folders.

Obviously this means I can't just search for a specific game .exe to get the directory needed because they are the same name, one idea I have thought of is to search for every mention of "hl2.exe" in the users computer and create a list of entries from that, it should in theory show the paths for each instance.

It's a bit difficult to explain without showing you but surprisingly enough a search for "hl2.exe" with Windows 7 shows no results..

I'd like to keep the programming language used to C# if possible!

Comment: UAC is probably preventing you from snooping around in the program files folder.

There's probably an XML file or something somewhere that keeps track of all the installed Steam games.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is foolproof, but here's a thought.

If you open Regedit and navigate to `Computer\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` (if you have a 32-bit version of Windows, leave out the `Wow6432Node` part of the path), you'll find one "Steam App XXX" for each installed game, where XXX is the Steam ID of the game installed.

Inside each, there's a DisplayName that gives you the game name, as well as InstallLocation for the path.

On my machine I have the following:

```
Steam App 40100 - Supreme Commander 2
Steam App 41500 - Torchlight
Steam App 630   - Alien Swarm
Steam App 8980  - Borderlands
```

Comment: Seems to work for me! All 4 of my installed Steam games are there. Torchlight's fun.

Comment: Will be more fun next year when they add multiplayer :)

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no executable link in that uninstall location, so you might not get exactly what you need.

Comment: Hmm, I cant seem to find any entries for it. Strange.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it the way Valve does, you will need code to read Steam's `clientregistry.blob` binary data file.

There is some floating around out there in C# (largely from sites where people are trying to pirate games.) I made a [Java version](https://github.com/DHager/hl2parse/tree/master/hl2parse-binary/src/main/java/com/technofovea/hl2parse/registry) for an SDK-tool project.

That will have the information you need about what games the user "owns", as well as some data about file paths.

Comment: This is a very old thread, but do you know if the .blob format has anything to do with what is usually refered to as a BLOB, in a database sense? Could that be used to read a .blob file instead of parsing the file manually (which appears to be a complicated process)?

Comment: If you mean something like "can I pop this into MySQL or PostgreSQL and have it come out OK", I very much doubt it. I assume it's a special-purpose format which is proprietary to Valve. I don't know if Valve has changed their format since I published the code, but [the blob unit-tests](https://github.com/DHager/hl2parse/blob/master/hl2parse-tests/src/test/java/com/technofovea/hl2parse/registry/ClientRegistryTest.java) are a useful place to start trying things out.

Answer (score 0):

As another angle of attack what about piggy-backing the windows games folder? 
as far as i know all steam games are automatically added to the windows games folder, you can find a list of all games and their launch executables in the regestry under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\GameUX
```

If you look under

```
c:\users\<username>\appdata\local\Microsoft\windows\game explorer
```

you might find info on users statistics